# Retrieve multiple arrays from Firebase iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have multiple arrays of objects in my Firebase Database.
I want to retrieve the items in each array and put them into a Swift dictionary. How would I get the values and insert them into a dictionary from a snapshot from Firebase?

How my Firebase Database is organized:

```
data: {
  firstKey: [
    {object},
    {object},
    ...
  ],
  secondKey: [
    {object},
    {object},
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

Line to retrieve the snapshot from Firebase:

```
ref.child("data").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in })
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a model for cast to your snapshot;

```
class YourModel: NSObject {
         var field1: String!
         var field2: Int!
         var field3: Bool!

         init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
            if let snapshotDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                field1 = snapshotDict["field1"] as? String
                field2 = snapshotDict["field2"] as? Int
                field3 = snapshotDict["field3"] as? Bool

            }
        }
       }
```

And get the data with for each in your callback;

```
var yourModels : [YourModel] = []
        ref.child("data").observe(.value, with: {
            snapshot in

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let model = YourModel.init(snapshot: (child as? FIRDataSnapshot)!)
                self.yourModels.append(model)
            }


        })
```